# Rubyであかさたなでgroup_by

Tags: ruby, 日本語

ひらがなの文字列の入った配列を、1文字目がどの行（あかさたなはまやらわ）かでグループ分けしたい時、  
どんな実装が考えられますでしょうか？

```
a = %w[あかがい うなぎ ほたて]
puts group_by_kana_row(a)

# { 'あ'=> ['あかがい', 'うなぎ'], 'は'=> ['ほたて'] }
```

Comment: 「あああ」「けけけ」など同じ文字が続く例しか挙がってませんが、例えば「あかさ」の様に複数グループにまたがる可能性のある文字列は存在しない、という前提でしょうか。

Comment: 質問文不十分で大変失礼いたしました。1文字目がどの行かでグループ分けしたい場合です。問題文を修正いたしました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

以下はどうでしょうか?

```
a = %w[あかがい うなぎ ほたて]

group = a.group_by do |item|
  case item[0]
  when /[ぁ-お]/  # ぁ, あ, ぃ, い, ぅ, う, ぇ, え, ぉ, お
    'あ'
  when /[か-ご]/  # か, が, き, ぎ, く, ぐ, け, げ, こ, ご
    'か'
  when /[さ-ぞ]/  # さ, ざ, し, じ, す, ず, せ, ぜ, そ, ぞ
    'さ'
  when /[た-ど]/  # た, だ, ち, ぢ, っ, つ, づ, て, で, と, ど
    'た'
  when /[な-の]/  # な, に, ぬ, ね, の
    'な'
  when /[は-ぽ]/  # は, ば, ぱ, ひ, び, ぴ, ふ, ぶ, ぷ, へ, べ, ぺ, ほ, ぼ, ぽ
    'は'
  when /[ま-も]/  # ま, み, む, め, も
    'ま'
  when /[ゃ-よ]/  # ゃ, や, ゅ, ゆ, ょ, よ
    'や'
  when /[ら-ろ]/  # ら, り, る, れ, ろ
    'ら'
  when /[ゎ-を]/  # ゎ, わ, ゐ, ゑ, を
    'わ'
  else
    item[0] # ん, その他
  end
end

group                           #=> {"あ"=>["あかがい", "うなぎ"], "は"=>["ほたて"]}
```

#### 参考

[正規表現を使うときに注意すべきこと#ひらがなの文字コード](https://qiita.com/kokorinosoba/items/78811d7e2b6bc424b1b1#%E3%81%B2%E3%82%89%E3%81%8C%E3%81%AA%E3%81%AE%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89)

Comment: ありがとうございます！パッと見て何をやっているのかわかりやすいのがいいですね！
ついでに教えていただけると嬉しいのですが、
item[0].chr のところは item.chr もしくは  item[0] だけでも同じ結果になるのかなと思ったのですが、[0].chr とするのは何か意図がありますでしょうか？

Comment: @ksh さん、すみません。ご指摘の通りですね。[String#chr](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/latest/class/String.html)には、Ruby1.8以前との互換性のためにあると記載がありました。修正いたします。(人に説明のできないコードを書いてはダメですね。気を付けます。)

Answer (score 4):

同じく、`group_by` を使ってみました。

```
def group_by_kana_row(a)
  keys = 'あかさたなはまやらわん'.chars
  keys_ord = 'ぁかさたなはまゃらゎん'.chars.map{|c| c.ord}
  a.group_by do |item|
    first = item[0].ord; r = 'no_match'
    keys_ord.each_with_index do |k, i|
      next if first > k
      r = keys[(first == k ? i : i-1)]
      break
    end
    r
  end
end

a = %w[あかがい うなぎ ほたて]
group_by_kana_row(a)
{"あ"=>["あかがい", "うなぎ"], "は"=>["ほたて"]}
```

Answer (score 1):

考え方は他の方の回答とだいたい同じなんですが、短く書いてみました。
わかりにくくなってる気もしないでもないですが…。

```
def group_by_kana_row(a)
  keys = "ぁかさたなはまゃらゎん".chars
  a.group_by do |x|
    keys.each_cons(2) do |s, e|
      break s if x < e
    end
  end.transform_keys{|k| k&.tr('ぁゃゎ', 'あやわ') }
end

a = %w[あかがい うなぎ ほたて]
p group_by_kana_row(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

拡張性を持たしてみました。(`&.`を使っているのでRuby 2.3以上)

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

# Unicode 10.0で追加された変体仮名には未対応
KANA_ROWS = {
  'あ' => [*(?ぁ..?お), ?ゔ],
  'か' => [*(?か..?ご), ?ゕ, ?ゖ],
  'さ' => [*(?さ..?ぞ)],
  'た' => [*(?た..?ど)],
  'な' => [*(?な..?の)],
  'は' => [*(?は..?ぼ)],
  'ま' => [*(?ま..?も)],
  'や' => [*(?ゃ..?よ), ?\u{1B001}],
  'ら' => [*(?ら..?ろ)],
  'わ' => [*(?ゎ..?を)],
  'ん' => [?ん],
}

def kana_row(str)
  KANA_ROWS.find { |_, list| str.start_with?(*list) } &.first
end

def group_by_kana_row(list)
  list.group_by(&method(:kana_row))
end

a = %w[あかがい うなぎ ほたて だ ゔぃくとりぃ abc]
puts group_by_kana_row(a)
```

※ U+1B001(「」"江"を崩した文字、環境によっては表示されない)はUnicode 6.0で追加された補助仮名で"や行え"です。

平仮名から始まらない場合は`nil`グループとしています。Unicode 10.0で追加された変体仮名に対応したい場合は、`KANA_ROWS`に足していくだけになります。また、片仮名も含める、アルファベットや数字もグループ化するといった拡張もKANA_ROWSに追加することで出来るようになっています(ただ、そのような拡張をする場合は名前は変えた方が良いかもしれない)。

Answer (score 0):

```
def group_by_kana_row(a)
 {
  'あ': a.select{|s| ('あ'..'お').to_a.include?(s[0])},
  'か': a.select{|s| ('か'..'こ').to_a.include?(s[0])},
  'さ': a.select{|s| ('さ'..'そ').to_a.include?(s[0])},
  'た': a.select{|s| ('た'..'と').to_a.include?(s[0])},
  'な': a.select{|s| ('な'..'の').to_a.include?(s[0])},
  'は': a.select{|s| ('は'..'ほ').to_a.include?(s[0])},
  'ま': a.select{|s| ('ま'..'も').to_a.include?(s[0])},
  'や': a.select{|s| ('や'..'よ').to_a.include?(s[0])},
  'ら': a.select{|s| ('ら'..'ろ').to_a.include?(s[0])},
  'わ': a.select{|s| ('わ'..'ん').to_a.include?(s[0])}
 }
end

group_by_kana_row(%w[あかがい うなぎ ほたて])
```